# How to calculate checksum of Address using Python

Tags: address, checksum

Lower Bit Range:      245
Upper Bit Range:      256

The Checksum of address `1H5aq8vssj9fCKdw2mYEn8enzpUMEBsUZ7` is `9ed6e860`.

---

I tried the following but got incorrect result `69e65f22`

```
import hashlib
import base58
def calculate_checksum(address):
    # Decode the Base58 address
    decoded_address = base58.b58decode(address)
    # Get the address without the checksum
    address_without_checksum = decoded_address[0:-4]
    sha256_hash = hashlib.sha256(hashlib.sha256(address_without_checksum).digest()).digest()
    calculated_checksum = sha256_hash[:4]
       checksum = calculated_checksum.hex()
    return checksum
address = "1H5aq8vssj9fCKdw2mYEn8enzpUMEBsUZ7"
checksum = calculate_checksum(address)
print(checksum)
```

How is it correctly calculated using python?

Comment: Instead of adding requested details in comments, simply [edit] your answer with the items.  Take a look at the change I made to your question to see how I was able to format the code you added.

Answer (score 0):

```
import hashlib
import base58
def calculate_checksum(address):
    decoded_address = base58.b58decode(address).hex()
    print(f"Checksum of {address} is {decoded_address[-8:]}")
    address_without_checksum = decoded_address[0:-8]
    sha256_hash = hashlib.sha256(hashlib.sha256(bytes.fromhex(address_without_checksum)).digest()).digest()
    calculated_checksum = sha256_hash[:4]
    checksum = calculated_checksum.hex()
    return checksum

address = "1H5aq8vssj9fCKdw2mYEn8enzpUMEBsUZ7"
checksum = calculate_checksum(address)
print(f"The calculated checksum is {checksum}")
```